# Where can I find this paper by Bonsall? (Quaterly Journal of Mathematics, 1991) (atomic decomposition, Minkowski functional)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am searching for the paper *Bonsall, F. F. (1991). A General Atomic Decomposition Theorem and Banach’s Closed
Range Theorem. The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, 42 9–14.* for the proof of
$$
\inf\{t > 0: x \in t \text{conv}(A)\}
= \inf\left\{ \sum_{a \in A} c_a: x = \sum_{a \in A} c_a a, \ c_a \ge 0 \ \forall a \in A\right\},
$$
where $A \subset \mathbb R^p$ is a compact subset whose elements are the extreme points of conv$(A)$, i.e. $a \not\in \text{conv}(A \setminus \{a\})$ for all $a \in A$ and the centroid of conv$(A)$ is the origin. (This is from The Convex Geometry of Linear Inverse Problems by Venkat Chandrasekaran, Benjamin Recht, Pablo A. Parrilo, and Alan S. Willsky)

I know that by Caratheodory theorem, one can represent the convex hull of $A$ as convex combinations of elements in $A$ with at most $p + 1$ summands, so I can write
$$
\text{LHS} = \inf\left\{ r > 0: \frac{x}{r} = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} c_k a_k, \ 
    N \le p + 1, \begin{array}{c}
        (c_k)_{k = 1}^{N} \subset [0, 1], \\
        (a_k)_{k = 1}^{N} \subset A,
    \end{array} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} c_k = 1 \right\}
$$
And I know that the LHS is $\infty$ (per convention $\inf(\emptyset) = \infty$) if $x$ is not in the affine hull of conv$(A)$. As conv$(A)$ is convex, aff$($conv$(A)) = $span$(A)$.

Comment: Try the [DOI link to Oxford University Press website for the article](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/42.1.9)

Comment: @Somos I don't have any access to that via my institution. The doi link just takes me to the same Oxford website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the question answered I note that the paper is already found and sent to the asker via e-mail.